# Wildlfy Swarm YAML properites file

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-swarm

i'm trying to run swarm with custom parameters, when I pass the properties options on command line, the server detects these options and runs properly, for example when I run this command :

> java -jar test.jar -Dswarm.https.certificate.generate=true

it generates a certificate and starts https on a specific port.

Now according to swarm documentation it's better to use a yaml config file, so I have created one with the properites I wanted. However when I specifiy the path to my yaml file in the command line :

> java -jar test.jar -S C:\Users\x17\test\modules\wsserver\project-default.yml

in this case, the file containing the properties is ignored, and the server starts with a default configuration.

Should the project-default file be in a specific folder in my project ? does anybody have an idea how to solve this issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There's a difference between `-s` and `-S`. The `-S` option, that you're trying to use, is used for selecting a `project-*.yml` file that's packaged together with the application, inside the uberjar. For example,

```
java -jar app-swarm.jar -S local
```

means that the file `project-local.yml` packaged inside the application is used.

If you want to set a full path to the YAML file, you need to use `-s`:

```
java -jar app-swarm.jar -s .../path/to/project-defaults.yml
```

See the documentation for more info: http://docs.wildfly-swarm.io/2018.1.0/#configuring-an-application-using-yaml

Comment: Hi @Ladicek, any way to refer with -S to the embedded default project-defaults.yml ? I can do it via -s and full path but want to simplify and convince to use the internal one. I tried with "-S defaults" and not worked

Comment: If you include `project-defaults.yml`, you don't have to select it with any parameter, it's enabled automatically.

Comment: Hi @Ladicek, I am using swarm version 2018.5.0. My project-defaults.yml is placed in src/main/resources. This works: java -jar ./target/core-hollow-swarm.jar ./target/core.war -s src/main/resources/project-defaults.yml
This doesn't: java -jar ./target/core-hollow-swarm.jar ./target/core.war.
I agree: the documentation says not to specify because it will be auto included. I am doing something fishy

Comment: Aaaa I forgot it's a hollow JAR. I don't recall the details now, but this is a known limitation of hollow JARs. You always have to specify a full path to the YAML file with `-s` when using a hollow JAR.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/thorntail/thorntail-examples/blob/master/config-options/cdi-injection/src/main/java/org/wildfly/swarm/examples/jaxrs/cdi/Controller.java

Can help you to figure out the issue.

```
@Inject
@ConfigurationValue("some.string.property")
String stringProperty;
```

is valid CDI injection solution.